# PHP excel file without PHPExcel

Tags: php, arrays, excel, phpexcel

I have to create a excel file having near about `350 columns` and `1000 rows`. I have developed code for this task using `PHPExcel`. But it takes `42secs` to create file. So I have to create excel file `without PHPExcel`. So I have developed a script in which data is identified by `"\t"` for different tab data. It takes just `2secs` to create file. But problem is that when I'm going to open that file (created by using "\t"), `message of corrupted file` is displayed. And on repairing that file, it works fine. But I can't understand that where I'm making mistake in script. If anyone can solve this problem either by using PHPExcel (less execution time) or by solving error of corrupt file, then answer will be appreciated. Here is my code (CakePHP 3).

Input Array like

```
// Do not confuse with { instead of [. It's okey.
// $export_data and $data both are same (Input array).
{
"0": {
    "customer_id": 1,
    "name": "John Stevens",
    "Date of 1 Purchase": "2014-08-05T00:00:00+0000",
    "Date of 2 Purchase": "2014-09-05T00:00:00+0000",
    "Date of 3 Purchase": "2014-10-05T00:00:00+0000",
    ...
    ...
    ... 350 Cols ...
    }
"1": {
    ...
    }
...
...
"999 Rows"
}
```

`Using PHPExcel`

```
$r = 1;
$filename = FILE_PATH . 'galliyan.xlsx';

$header = array_keys($export_data[0]);

$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
$col = 0;
foreach ($header as $field) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
    $col++;
}
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($filename);
chmod($filename, 0777);
$r++;

$objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
foreach($export_data as $row) {
    $col = 0;
    foreach ($row as $ro) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellvalueByColumnAndRow($col, $r, $ro);
        $col++;
    }

    $r++;
}
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($filename);
chmod($filename, 0777);
```

EDIT (UPDATED CODE)

```
$filename = FILE_PATH . 'galliyan.xlsx';
$header = array_keys($export_data[0]);

$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$col = 0;
foreach ($header as $field) {
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
    $col++;
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($export_data, null, 'A2');
$writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$writer->save($filename);
chmod($filename, 0777);
```

`Using "\t"`

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!$flag) {
        $header = array();
        // display field/column names as first row
        $header = array_keys($row);
        $header = $this->setExcelHeaders($header);
        $this->createExcelFile($dir_name, $filename, $header, $export_type);
        $flag = TRUE;
    }

    array_walk($row, array($this, 'cleanData'));
    array_push($values, $row);

}

$values = $this->setValues($values);
$this->writeExcelFile($dir_name, $filename, $values);

function setExcelHeaders($hdrs) {
    $header = '';
    foreach ($hdrs as $title_val) {
        $header .= $title_val . "\t";
    }
    return $header;
}

function createExcelFile($dir_name, $filename, $header, $export_type = '') {
    $fp = fopen($dir_name . "/" . $filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, "$header\n");
    fclose($fp);

    $permission = Configure::read('Config.PERMISSION');
    if ($export_type == "") {
        chmod($dir_name, $permission);
    }
    chmod($dir_name . "/" . $filename, $permission);
}

public function cleanData(&$str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if (strstr($str, '"'))
        $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

private function setValues($all_vals) {
    $data = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_vals); $i++) {
        $line = '';
        foreach ($all_vals[$i] as $value) {
            if ((!isset($value)) || ( $value == "")) {
                $value = "\t";
            }
            else {
                $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data .= trim($line) . "\n";
    }
    return $values = str_replace("\r", "", $data);
}

function writeExcelFile($dir_name, $filename, $data) {
    $fp = fopen($dir_name . "/" . $filename, 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "$data");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: You can reduce the time for the PHPExcel script by writing the file only once rather than twice

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to fix your non-PHPExcel version, and create a CSV file as an alternative to an OfficeOpenXML-format xlsx file, use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function rather than a bad homebrew code

Comment: @Mark. your solution is beneficial as it reduced time by 2-3 sec. I have also tried this solution as you suggested in another question. i.e, `$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(); $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $ro, $field);`

Comment: @MarkBaker. As per your second suggestion, I have to create excel file, not csv. So I think I cant use fputcsv() to write tabular data in file.

Comment: The non-PHPExcel code that you've posted ___is___ generating a csv file, not a native format Excel file...... it wasn't my suggestion, it was a comment on your code; you're creating a csv file with a tab-separator using a badly-written homebrew

Comment: For the PHPExcel solution, you can also use the `fromArray()` method instead of looping over the columns in each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned "without PHPExcel", have you tried looking at alternatives that can be faster than PHPExcel? For instance, you can generate a 350x1000 XLSX spreadsheet with [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) (https://github.com/box/spout) in just a few seconds.

Generating a CSV file is also a good alternative and I'd recommend you going this route if you can. The export process will be way faster! But don't try to reinvent the wheel, there a already a lot of CSV writer out there, ready to use (Spout and PHPExcel both have one for instance).

Comment: If you want to go only for .xls (large file as per mentioned in question) files, Spout is best in terms of response time.

Comment: My response time is decreased from 42 Secs(PHPExcel) to 5 Secs(Spout). But I will not use Spout for smaller file. I will go for PHPExcel  if file is 100rows * 50cols (near about)